# Vlookup in excel and vba

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Below I have 2 files, 1 is a item master

**File A**

```
Article     Colour    Size    
ABC           Blue       M       
DEF           black      S      
GHI           Red        S
```

**File B - item master**

```
Article     Colour    Size  
ABC           black      M      
DEF           black      S      
GHI           Red        L
```

I would like to do a vlookup and create a exception column that will return:

```
Article     Colour    Size    Exception
ABC           Blue       M      Wrong Color
DEF           black      S      No exception
GHI           Red        L      Wrong Size
```

Is it possible to use VBA to do it?
Hope someone can help.Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

ITEM MASTER

```
Article     Colour    Size  
ABC           black      M   
ABC           blue       M
ABC           black      S   
DEF           black      S      
GHI           Red        L
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use `VBA`? Are you inclined to it or have you tried any code to achieve what you want?

Comment: For now i only know how to use vlookup.. not sure how to start on vba as have nv done it before..

Comment: So `VBA` is not a necessity? A formula will do then? Because I think that is the best approach here not unless you have other considerations.

Comment: what i am afraid is becos the data tt will be used it in a huge file.. if lets say vba is not necessary.. what would be a better way to deal with this? very new here.. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what I thought the best way.
I use `Index` and `Match` Function for this.
Assuming your data looks like this and you're checking exception referenced to another open file.

First, set-up a *Match Function Helper Column* using this formula:
`=MATCH(A2,[Book2]Sheet1!$A:$A,0)`

[image]

Second, use *Index Function with If* to determine exception. Use below formula:
**Edit1:**
`=IF(INDEX([Book2]Sheet1!$B:$B,E2)=B2,IF(INDEX([Book2]Sheet1!$C:$C,E2)=C2,"No Exception","Wrong Size"),IF(INDEX([Book2]Sheet1!$C:$C,E2)=C2,"Wrong Color","Both Exception"))`

[image: Index Funtion]

This is assuming your `Item Master` data is in `Book2`.
Recalculation speed is fast using this formula, although I cannot give you exact numbers.
Hope this somehow helps you.

Comment: sorry.. need to add on.. if for example.. i have article ABC but have different colour and size.. how do i go about doing it?

Comment: See **Edit1**. That will mark article with different colour and size *Both Exception*

Comment: Sorry.. what i mean is like in my item master i have 1 article but in different color and size.. as shown in edit1

Comment: Then how do you decide what prompt to return? It can be *Wrong Color* or *Worng Size* for article *ABC* based on your **Edit1**

Comment: is it possible to like check the 3 fields (Article, Colour, Size) in the whole item master to see if there is a matching data... and if there is no matching one.. then prompt wrong color or wrong size or maybe even no such article? Becos i tried using my data and by using the index, when there are repeat articles but with different size/color in the item master that is matching with the check list, it will also prompt as wrong color/size as it only recognize that values in that index.

Comment: Yes that is possible. But returning the correct prompt would be messy. If however, you really need the exact prompts for a particular *article-colour-size* combination, then `VBA` will be easier I think. Well, let's see...

Comment: Eh.. Any advice on how to go about doing it? =)